# java data not showing in jsp viw when passing from controller in spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

In view the ${item} values not showing in view.i'm new in java spring.please help me.

```
<c:forEach items="${billItems}" var="item" varStatus="loop">
        ${item}
       <%-- <tr class="text_center border_left">
            <td ></td>
            <td >${loop.index + 1}</td>
            <td >${item.code}  # ${item.productName} </td>
            <td>${item.quantity}</td>
            <td>${item.unit}</td>
            <td class="col-integer">${item.price}</td>
            <td class="col-integer">${item.quantity * item.price}</td>
            <td></td>
            <c:set var="temp" value="${item.quantity * item.price}"/>
            <c:set var="total" value="${total + temp}"/>
        </tr>--%>
    </c:forEach>'
```

In view the ${item} values not showing in view .i am new in java spring.please help me.The controller is in below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/billing/print/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String billPrint(@PathVariable int id, Model model, HttpServletRequest request)
        throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
    if (request.getSession().getAttribute("loginUser") != null) {
        Bill bill;
        bill = obsJDBCTemplate.getLastBillForPrinting(id);
        Customer customer = obsJDBCTemplate.getCustomer(bill.getCustomerId());
        bill.setCustomerName(customer.getName());

        List<BillItem> billItems = obsJDBCTemplate.getBillItemList(bill.getBillId());

        for (BillItem billItem : billItems) {
            Product product = obsJDBCTemplate.getProduct(billItem.getIdproduct());
            billItem.setProductName(product.getName());
            billItem.setCode(product.getCode());
            billItem.setUnit(product.getUnit());
        }

        model.addAttribute("billItems", billItems);
        model.addAttribute("h1_label","Irfan Mughal");
        model.addAttribute("h4_br1","jewen hanna hassan mobile center garden town Lahore");
        model.addAttribute("h4_br2","");
        model.addAttribute("h4_br3","");
        model.addAttribute("bill", bill);
        model.addAttribute("previous_balance", obsJDBCTemplate.getDebitOfCustomer(customer.getIdCustomer()));
        return "Print";

    } else
        return "redirect:/";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the correct taglib header <%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>, not having this can cause no end of problems with spring model objects. have a look at http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-hello-world-example/ it's a really good place to start

Comment: I've just noticed that you've commented out the table rows, and your trying to print out each item, all you'll get with that is the object reference within the list. you won't be able to get access to the item data as that is embedded within the item object.